# Making a numerical Pyramid

Tags: java

Firstly this is homework so I'm not looking for an answer to the question just a pointer as to where to go next. I'm supposed to take a user input (x) in this instance 3, and return a pyramid that looks like this based on the input;

```
    1
  2 1 2
3 2 1 2 3
```

I tried to break the problem down into printing from 1 up to x and from x down to one and to concatenate the two. This is not working, at all!
This is my code so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Q8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter an integer 1-15:");
        int input = user_input.nextInt();

        for(int row=1;row<=input;row++)
        {
            for(int back=input;back>=2;back--)
            {
                System.out.print(back+" ");
            }
            for(int col=1;col<=row;col++)
            {
            System.out.print(col+" ");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }




    }
}
```

The problem is rather than printing the above pyramid it prints;

```
 3 2 1
 3 2 1 2
 3 2 1 2 3
```

Comment: tbodt How did you change the second set of numerals into a formatted shape also?

Comment: Please try and use proper Java formatting, your code is very hard to read.

Comment: I've edited your post to have slightly better formatting, will show up once it's "peer reviewed".

Comment: @tbodt, `[homework]` is blacklisted for a reason.  We don't need an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
        for(int back=input;back>=2;back--)
        {
            System.out.print(back+" ");
        }
```

You are looping back and printing the numbers every time from input! That means that even in the first row, you will be printing 3 2 1. What you should do is initialize `back` as `row`... although the problem with that is that in that case, the pyramid will be left-aligned.

If you want the pyramid to be properly centered, you will need to fill out the space before the numbers in all the rows (except the last one). You can do this with a similar loop, except just print empty spaces. The pyramid may still come out looking a bit weird though, depending on the font, because characters are not necessarily the same width; it should probably be sufficient for you though.

Comment: Hi Marconius, Thanks so much for your help. The first paragraph of your answer set me straight, after that I placed another for loop before the first one for white space and just played around with it to get the pyramid to align, should I update the code in my question to reflect the updated answer? Or do I leave it as is?

Comment: You should leave the code as is; accept my edit if you can (not entirely sure how, sorry) just so the format is a bit better. Glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 0):

In the first row you should replace 3 and 2 with spaces so in the first for loops where you are using back and col you have to introduce an other variable to print spaces instead of back or col  the number
something like:

```
  int input = user_input.nextInt();
     int i = 1;

    for(int row=1;row<=input;row++)
    {

        for(int back=input;back>=2;back--)
        {

            if(back > i){

            System.out.print(" ");

             }else{

            System.out.print(back);

            } 
            i--;

            System.out.print(" ");
        }
```

Comment: For reference, `System.out.print(((back > i) ? " " : ("" + back)) + " ");` could replace all but the `i--;` in your inner loop.

Comment: that was not the complete logic it is a code snippet for better understanding